# How can I use Django 3 and jQuery to sort <li> items on all paginated pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

Currently I can sort li items on one page but not all paginated pages.

I select an item from a dropdown list to sort by various attributes based on a model.  Here is the jquery for one of the items.

```
var sortIconsetsTitle = function () { 
    $("ul.iconsets-list li[data-sort-title]").detach().sort(function(a,b){
        return String($(b).attr('data-sort-title')) < String($(a).attr('data-sort-title'))
    }).appendTo($("ul.iconsets-list"))
    $('div.iconsets-sort span').text("Title");  // show the order by name
}; 
$('li a.sort-title').on('click', function () {  sortIconsetsTitle(); }); //make it so
```

The code works beautifully - but only on one page.

How can I use this code to return results from all the paginated pages?